# Re-position and change buttons to images?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

I am trying to re-position the button so that it is in the bottom right corner of the frame, but everything I try such as setLocation and setBounds, don't seem to do anything. Also, how would I change the button to an image? So that it is still a button, but an image is displayed.

```
package TrainCounselor;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Start extends JPanel {

public Start() {

    // Game Properties
    setOpaque(false);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Image a = Toolkit
            .getDefaultToolkit()
            .getImage(
                    "C:/Users/Mel/workspace/camptycoon/javagame/src/javagame/background1.png");
    g.drawImage(a, 0, 0, this);
    super.paint(g);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Put Image");
    JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    startButton.setLayout(null);
    startButton.setLocation(50, 50);
    Start c = new Start();
    c.add(startButton);
    myFrame.add(c);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setTitle("Counselor Training");
    myFrame.setSize(755, 600);
    myFrame.setResizable(false);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to re-position the button so that it is in the bottom right corner of the frame

Use the appropriate Layout Managers.

I would start by using a JPanel with a FlowLayout that is right aligned. Then you add this panel to the "SOUTH" of the BoderLayout which is used by the JFrame.

See [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

Note when you add the Start class to the frame you are adding it to the "CENTER", not the south. Also, custom painting is done by override the paintComponent() method, not the paint() method and don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent() before you draw the image, not after.

> Also, how would I change the button to an image? So that it is still a button, but an image is displayed.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).